# using text files as lists in python

Tags: python, format, text-files

This is the updated program, with help from the answers you all have provided. I now see and understand how to display the questions and answers as pairs, my only concerns now is how I could neaten up the output for questions and answers. For example :

```
    1. question etc..
    a.answer
    b.answer                 
    c.answer
    d.answer
    e.none of the above

#
#Actual program------
    def main():
        print("Welcome to the Garbology Quiz")
        questionList = getQuestionList()
        answerList = getFormat()
        display = printanswers(questionList,answerList)


    def getQuestionList():
       with open("questions.txt") as questionFile:
            questionList = questionFile.readlines()

       return questionList

    def getFormat():

       formatchoice = input("Would you like the answers printed in metric or american format? (m or     a): ")
       formatchoice = formatchoice.lower()

       while formatchoice != "a" and formatchoice != "m":
          formatchoice = input("Invalid input, please enter a correct value (m or a): ")
          formatchoice = formatchoice.lower()

       if formatchoice == "a":
          answerPath = "american-answers.txt"
       else:
          answerPath = "metric-answers.txt"

       with open(answerPath) as answerFile:
          answerList = answerFile.readlines()

          return answerList

    def printanswers(questionList,answerList):
       for i in range(0,len(questionList)):
          print(questionList[i])
          print(answerList[i])




    main()
```

Comment: You could load all the questions and answers into a dictionary.

Comment: Is there a way I could format the output of the printed list to display like a test? Like "question... \n A. answer \n B. answer \n etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works quite well and is not as bloated:

```
def readFile(f):
    fileObj = open(f)
    result = fileObj.read().split("\n")
    fileObj.close()
    return result

questions = readFile("questions.txt")
ameriAnswers = readFile("standard.txt")
metricAnswers = readFile("metric.txt")

while True:
    choice = raw_input("Would you like the answers printed in metric or american format? (m or a): ")
    if choice == 'a':
        for i in range(0, len(questions)): #Assumes the questions file and answer files have the same item count!
            print "Q: ", questions[i]
            print "A: ", ameriAnswers[i]

    elif choice == 'm':
        for i in range(0, len(questions)): #Assumes the questions file and answer files have the same item count!
            print "Q: ", questions[i]
            print "A: ", metricAnswers[i]


    elif choice == 'q':
        break

    else:
        print "Invalid Input!"

    print "\n\n\n\n\n" #Some spacing
```

If you wanted to only print the first 3 answers, you could replace the for loops with the following:

```
for i in range(0, 3):
```

Note that there is no error checking in this, so if the files do not contain what the program expects, it may crash.

Comment: Is there a way I could format the output of the printed list to display like a test? Like "question... \n A. answer \n B. answer \n etc.

Comment: Absolutely, but you would have to include the false answers as well in the text documents. Personally I would use commas to separate answers, put the correct answer at the beginning and randomly shuffle them when they're displayed, then check the string to see if its correct. But that is far beyond the scope of your original question.

Comment: The false answers are included as well in the text documents, but they aren't seperate entries in the list

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough equivalent to your code:

```
# Written for Python 3.

def main():
    print("Welcome to the Garbology Quiz")
    questionList = getQuestionList()
    answerList = getAnswerList()

    print(questionList)
    print(answerList)

def getQuestionList():
   with open("questions.txt") as questionFile:
        questionList = questionFile.readlines()

   return questionList

def getAnswerList():
    formatchoice = input("Would you like the answers printed in metric or american format? (m or a): ")
    formatchoice = formatchoice.lower()

    while formatchoice != "a" and formatchoice != "m":
        formatchoice = input("Invalid input, please enter a correct value (m or a): ")
        formatchoice = formatchoice.lower()

    if formatchoice == "a":
        answerPath = "american-answers.txt"
    else:
        answerPath = "metric-answers.txt"

    with open(answerPath) as answerFile:
        answerList = answerFile.readlines()

    return answerList

main()
```

Comment: Is there a way I could format the output of the printed list to display like a test? Like "question... \n A. answer \n B. answer \n etc.

Answer (score 0):

You've read the questions and answers into lists, now you can just index them. One trick is to zip them into a list of pairs first, so later iteration is a bit tighter. `readlines` doesn't remove new lines, so I'll take them out also.

```
q_and_a = zip((l.strip() for l in questionList), (l.strip() for l in format))
del questionList, format
for i in range(3):
    print("Question %d: %s\nAnswer: %s\n\n" % (i+1, q_and_a[i][0], q_and_a[i][1]))
```

Also, this compare doesn't work:

```
while formatchoice != "a" or formatchoice != "m":
```

You want to 'and' them, or better yet:

```
while formatchoice not in ('a', 'm'):
```

Comment: I'm really new to programming, so I don't really understand zipping them into pairs

Comment: Its not really necessary - you can just keep the two lists and index them with the same number - but zip combines them into a single list. For example, `zip(['q1','q2','q3'], ['a1','a2','a3'])` gives you `[('q1', 'a1'), ('q2', 'a2'), ('q3', 'a3')]`.

Comment: would I be able to just:  zip(questionList, answerList)?

Comment: I'm about to post my current input/ output. I'm still confused as to how to neaten up the output.

Comment: I considered this solution as well when I rewrote the script, but found it too complex to introduce to a beginner.